# In Spring Rest, how do I override the GET and PUT calls?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

My Spring REST program, a slight extension of a Stephen Zerhusen demo using Json Web Tokens (JWT), works OK -- as far as it goes. I added an Option object, and I can GET, PUT and POST using just an Option class (@Entity) and an OptionRepository interface (extends JpaRepository)

I'm now trying, but failing, to restrict the returned data to just what the logged-in user has rights to.  As an example, suppose that my logged in user only has rights to Option values 1, 3, and 5.

- If I have a service call like GET /option I should not return Option values 2 or 4.
- If I have a service call like GET /option/2 I should get back a HTTP 404 result.

I understand that once the user has logged in I can get their user information through a Principal object reference.  [Such a solution was offered in this previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955406/spring-boot-and-jpa-repository-how-to-filter-a-get-by-id), and other pages also offer similar solutions.

My immediate problem is to find where I can affect the GET and PUT behavior of /option.  Here is all that I added to an existing, working demo.  First the entity defining class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="choice")
public class Option implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id = Utilities.INVALID_ID;

    @Column(name="value", length=50, nullable=false)
    private String value;

    @Column(name="name", length=100, nullable=false)
    private String name;

    public Long getId() { return this.id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getValue() { return this.value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Now the JpaRepository interface extension:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="option", path="option")
public interface OptionRepository extends JpaRepository<Option, Long> {
}
```

I merely added those two files to the program and GET, PUT and POST work. BTW, it turns out that if I comment out the @RepositoryRestResource statement the call to /option/1 returns HTTP 404.  Some documentation suggests it isn't needed, but I guess it really is.

Now to filter the output.  Let's pretend to filter by making the server always return Option (id = 5).  I do this by:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="option", path="option")
public interface OptionRepository extends JpaRepository<Option, Long> {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/option/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Query("from Option o where o.id = 5")
    public Iterable<Option> getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id);
}
```

When I run this server and do GET /option/1 I get back ... Option 1, not Option 5. The @Query isn't used.

What is the magic needed to affect the GET, PUT, etc?

Thanks,

Jerome.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you.. )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Resource Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_resourceprocessor_interface) to manipulate returned resources:

```
@Component
public class OptionResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Option>> {

    @Override
    public Resource<Option> process(Resource<Option> resource) {
        Option option = resource.getContent();
        if (/* Logged User is not allowed to get this Option */ ) {
            throw new MyCustomException(...);
        } else {
            return resource;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create custom [Exception handler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc), for example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionsHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new MyCustomMessage(e), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

To add some logic to PUT/POST/DELETE request you can use a custom [Event Handler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler), for example:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(Option.class) 
public class OptionEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleBeforeSave(Option option) {
        if (/* Logged User is not allowed to save this Option */ ) {
            throw new MyCustomException(...);
        }   
    }
}
```

You can find more SDR usage examples in my sample [project](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes)...